# Tablesorter: Only allow external filter to search child rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

Goal:

- Have the "internal" filters (that is to say the individual columns' filters) only filter based on their own respective columns. Ignore child row data.
- Have an external filter that can filter based on all the table's data **including child rows**.

Issue:

- I can get the external filter access the child rows by including `filter_childrows: true` in the widget options of Table Sorter. However, that leads to the individual column filters to access data in every other column, too.

Is there a way for me to essentially say: "Internal column filters, only pay attention to your data and disregard child rows. External filter, pay attention to everything including the child rows."?

If it's of any help to understanding my question, I've attached a screenshot of what I'm working with.[image: Sample Data]

Comment: I didn't find anything about "child rows" in the [tablesorter documentation](http://tablesorter.com/docs/). Are you referring to another jQuery plugin?

Comment: Hi Roberto, thanks for the quick response!

Here's a link discussing some of it: https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-child-rows.html

Answer (score 0):

According to the [tablasorter documentation](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#), there is a property from version 2.22.0 called `filter_childByColumn` that states:

> If true, queries will search child row content by column (v2.22.0)

So you should set it to false, but actuallly that is its default value so either you are setting it manually to true or you don't have the 2.22.0 version.

Comment: Unfortunately, including that option (set to true) results in the external filter to not be able to access child rows. It's probably worth noting that my external filter `input` has `data-column="all"`.